# Running count based on field

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to get a running count for each user with the query below

Does anyone know how I can do this? If I remove `where user = 1` it gives me an overall running count due to the grouping.

I'd like to get running counts for user 1 through N. I'd rather not run the query for each user individually as there are a few million.

```
SET @runtot:=0;
SELECT q1.t, q1.user, q1.c, (@runtot := @runtot + q1.c) AS rt
FROM (
   SELECT
     time AS t,
     user,
     COUNT(distinct `post`) AS c
   FROM
     interactions
   WHERE user = 1
   GROUP BY
     user,time
   ORDER BY
     user
) AS q1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
SET @runtot:=0;
SET @last_user:=NULL;
SELECT
  q1.t,
  q1.user,
  q1.c,
  CASE WHEN @last_user=q1.user
       THEN @runtot := @runtot + q1.c
       ELSE @runtot:=q1.c END AS rt,
  @last_user:=q1.user
FROM (
  ...
) AS q1
```

This query will keep last user into the `@last_user` variable, and whenever the user changes it will start the count again.